# How can I optimize my database queries using my actual django model?

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-templates

I can't post image because I'm new so here's a link of [what I want](http://diobla.info/tmp/conf.png).

So, I have the model on the left and I want the view on the right.
As of now, I'm looping over every thread I'm interested in. Template code:

```
{% for thread in threadlist %}
{% for post in thread.postlist %}
...
```

Model code:

```
class Thread (models.Model):
...    
def postlist(self):
    posts = list(self.post_set.all())
    return [posts.pop(0)] + posts[-2:]
```

There must be a way to do this with less queries by joining columns or something. I'm pretty new to Python/Django and I don't really know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [select_related](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4) . This will make the query follow joins so you end up with one larger query, instead of many smaller ones.

The docs are pretty thorough.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/many_to_many/) you [should](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries) be using post_set.all().
I'm pretty sure that the queries are joined by django behind the scenes, and that its lazy.
Meaning it won't be loaded until its needed.

From the documentation:

> QuerySets are lazy -- the act of creating a QuerySet doesn't involve any database activity. You can stack filters together all day long, and Django won't actually run the query until the QuerySet is evaluated.

Comment: I'm doing a query for each thread, that's 10+ queries per page.  
I want only 1 loop instead of having 2 nested ones.

"QuerySets are lazy" means they're only executed when necessary and here every one of them is. My actual solution is not optimal.